# Python - Convert a requests response in JSON format to a Pandas DF

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am using requests to return a response in a JSON format that looks like the image below.

[image: JSON Format]

I have tried to convert it to a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response)
```

but that produces a df with columns "currentPage", "data", "message", etc.  I want the dataframe to be based on the "data" dictionary, including the next level down of "hpData".

How do I structure the conversion to get to those next levels?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
json = response.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(json['data'])
```

From this source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-nested-json-structures-to-pandas-dataframes/